# How to update Reference Array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Group Collection, which is having a Reference array of Members. Two Objects are inter-connected like follow. When I am adding new members to the group the members field of Group object needed to be updated. How can I do this with a `mongoose` `update` operator.

```
var MemberSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        default:null
    },
    user_id:{
        type : Schema.ObjectId,
        ref : 'User',
        default : null
    }
});

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        default:null
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        default:null
    },
    members:[MemberSchema],

},{collection:"groups"});
```

Thank You in advance.

**Update**

I added a sample document of group.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586a2e694467c41218b302c3"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("586a2e694467c41218b302c6"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("58171d75e72bf516f92dcd4e"),
            "name" : "Lakmal Kapukotuwa"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("586a2e694467c41218b302c5"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5821807516325e127f59438e"),
            "name" : "Prasad Perera"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("586a2e694467c41218b302c4"),
            "user_id" : ObjectId("586263515356e908de6c899a"),
            "name" : "Sadun Prasad"
        }
    ],
    "description" : "Des 1",
    "name" : "My group",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link to your question to show us an example list of the new members you want added to the `members` array? From what I gather it may be a simple case of using the `$push` operator with `$each` if you are supplying a list with member objects and also depending on how the objects in the array are structured, hence the request to add more info about the members you wish to add.

Comment: @chridam. Sure. I have updated the question. Also thank you for the quick respond.

Comment: @chridam. Yes we can handle it with $push operator. Please post this as an answer, where I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sending the new members as a list of objects with the following structure e.g.

```
membersListToAdd = [ 
    {
        "user_id": "58171d75e72bf516f92dcd4e",
        "name": "foo"
    }, 
    {
        "user_id": "5821807516325e127f59438e",
        "name": "bar"
    }
]
```

then use **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)** with **[`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/)** modifier in an update as follows:

```
var query = { name: 'My Group' },
    options = {},
    callback = function (err, result) { console.log(result); };
Group.update(query, { $push: { members: { $each: membersListToAdd } } }, options, callback)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this wrong,

no need to have links in both collections and no need to nest models

try this instead

```
var Group = mongoose.model("Group", new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String
    },
    description: {
        type:String
    },
}));

Group.virtual("users", {
    ref: "User",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "groups"
});

var User =  mongoose.model("User", new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    groups: [{
        type : Schema.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Group'
    }]
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: Why OP is doing wrong? I am genuinely asking why using virtual is a better solution. Thank you in advance and regards